# Connect to a database using Python in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, python-3.x, database-connection

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated) with Microsoft Python Tools for Visual Studio installed.

I have connected an existing database by going to `Tools` -> `Connect to a Database...`.  I can now see my database in server explorer.

How do I access that database from my python application?  Should I use [pyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/)?  Am I already connected to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible through Server Explorer.

> We don't have any Server Explorer integration in PTVS yet

Source: [PTVS forum](https://pytools.codeplex.com/discussions/547548)